# Binding Angular element to scope outside of a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Still quickly learning AngularJS, what I have below is a simple test sample displying a listing using `ng-repeat` and what will eventually be a popup.

---

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/TFmjQ/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="main">
    <div id="person-info"></div>
    <div id="people" ng-controller="PeopleController" ng-cloak>
        <div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class-even="'even'">
            <a href="" ng-click="showPersonInfo()">( more )</a> <span>{{person.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('main',[]);

// Main Model
var model = [];
for (var i=0,n=10; i<n; i++){
    model[model.length] = {'name': 'Person '+ i, 'description': 'Person ' + i + ' description'};
}

// Main Controller
function PeopleController ($scope) {
    $scope.people = model;

    $scope.showPersonInfo = function (){
        document.getElementById('person-info').innerHTML = this.person.description;
    };
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/TFmjQ/)

---

There's two issues I have with the above:

1. Using DOM lookup/manipulation in the click controller feels wrong
2. Related to the first point, there must be a better way to bind an element outside the controller to model in scope.  Ideally, I'd like an answer similar to: `<div id="person-info">{{$scope.person.description}}</div>`, where the click controller only needs to focus on maybe setting the `$scope.person`, or some other event handling.

---

*The docs have gotten much better since I last looked at Angular, but I welcome comments to improve readability, or best/common practice.  For instance, I will probably get grief from using "main" as the app name :)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access outside the scope of the **PeopleController** controller like as given below use `$rootScope`

---

**OUTSIDE CONTROLLER SCOPE ([Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/5/))**

**html**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="main">
     <div id="person-info">{{desc}}</div>
    <div id="people" ng-controller="PeopleController" ng-cloak>
        <div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class-even="'even'">
            <a href="" ng-click="showPersonInfo(person.description)">( more )</a> <span>{{person.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
angular.module('main',[]);
// Main Model
var model = [];
for (var i=0,n=10; i<n; i++){
    model[model.length] = {'name': 'Person '+ i, 'description': 'Person ' + i + ' description'};
}
// Main Controller
function PeopleController ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.people = model;

    $scope.showPersonInfo = function (personDesc){
        $rootScope.desc=personDesc;
    };
}
```

---

**INSIDE CONTROLLER SCOPE ([Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/4/))**

My suggestion is to encapsulate `<div id="person-info">{{value}}</div>` within your controller **PeopleController**

**html**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="main">

    <div id="people" ng-controller="PeopleController" ng-cloak>
        <div id="person-info">{{desc}}</div>
        <div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class-even="'even'">
            <a href="" ng-click="showPersonInfo(person.description)">( more )</a> <span>{{person.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**script**

```
   angular.module('main',[]);

// Main Model
var model = [];
for (var i=0,n=10; i<n; i++){
    model[model.length] = {'name': 'Person '+ i, 'description': 'Person ' + i + ' description'};
}

// Main Controller
function PeopleController ($scope) {
    $scope.people = model;

    $scope.showPersonInfo = function (personDesc){
        $scope.desc=personDesc;
    };
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks Nidhish, I remember seeing `$rootScope` at a recent conference but couldn't remember the name of it.

Comment: I modified to pass `person` to the click handler and added it to the $rootScope.  I was surprise I didn't have to clone the object -- it seemed to stay in scope/memory for the duration of what I needed.  This allowed me to be more explicit elsewhere in the code; for example `{{person.description}}` was more meaningful then `{{description}}`.
=========================================
I'm not quite sure what the purpose of caching `angular.module()` is.  I thought that I might be able to use this globally to refer to objects in scope, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggest for you: don't use element method in controller, the element action only allow in directives.

About your code:
I optimize like this:

```
`<div class="container" ng-app="main" ng-controller="PeopleController">
  <div id="person-info">{{desc}}</div>
  <div id="people" ng-cloak>
    <div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <a href="" ng-click="showPersonInfo(person)">( more )</a> <span>{{person.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`

function PeopleController ($scope) {
  $scope.people = model;

  $scope.showPersonInfo = function (person){
    //console.log(person)
    $scope.desc = person.description;
  };
}
```

Comment: use element method in controller, it's difficult to test it(e2e).